# Use newest Gecko/Xulrunner in C# application

Tags: c#, firefox, chromium, gecko, geckofx

I'm aware of this: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx

However the newest version of Gecko isn't always available there and Xulrunner 22 doesn't work with Geckofx 21.

Any way to use the latest version in my C# application?

Apple's WebKit isn't supported anymore on Windows and there appears to be no proper Chromium wrapper for .NET either. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have a particular need for Xulrunner 22 over Xulrunner 21?

Comment: No, but since it has improvements over 21, I'd like to use the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use GeckoFX (I'm not surprised), you always have to use proper XulRunner version to concrete GeckoFX wrapper implementation. Newest GeckoFX wrapper version supports XulRunner v.22 indeed:

https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0/downloads

but ensure that you are realy able to take advantage of newest Xul. Usually there are always small changes between Xul versions - but they are and it can affect the compatibility of your application.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

GekoFX is a .Net wrapper for XulRunner. Whatever version of GekoFX is available you must of course use that version of XulRunner. Remember that Firefox is not always using the latest version of XulRunner.